# How to configure Veeam (or other) to backup fileserver with daily/weekly/monthly restore points?

Tags: backup, backup-restoration, veeam

I want to backup a fileserver of around 4TB with:

- Daily restore points for 14 days
- Weekly restore points for 4 weeks
- Monthly restore points 6 months

What is the best way to do this taking in account the fact that we want to save as much space as possible while still retaining good restore possibilities.

I was thinking to configure 3 different jobs (3 fulls with each incrementals on top). Or can I use one full backup with 3 jobs to save that each add increments on that 1 full to save space or is that very risky (keeping only 1 full)?

Should I have more than 1 active full?

Maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veeam supports a grandfather-father-son backup scheme using the built-in Backup Copy functionality. Create a Backup Copy job, and look in the Target section of the wizard. [image: Veeam backup retention illustration].

The copies will be stored as full backups so they can be independently restored without having to trust that a possibly several years old full backup still exists somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, so does this keep a full backup everytime? If so then we don't have enough space. It's 4TB but our backup repo is only 22TB.

Comment: If you don't have a lot of change to the file server you might try running "forever incremental" backups for the desired number of generations and ensure the backups remain valid by configuring a SureBackup job that attempts starting (and optionally testing) the file server after each backup job. But generally speaking I would say that it is in the company's interest to ensure they have good enough backups for a long enough period, and unfortunately that does cost money like everything else.

Comment: Hi Mikael, thanks for your help again. Is it a best practice to keep a full every month?

Comment: The best practice is that you should be reasonably sure that you can restore what you need for a) company needs, and b) legal requirements. I like having at least a month of backups quickly available in an incremental chain, and for important systems I do store monthly backups for ten years for legal reasons.

Comment: ..And don't forget that you need off-site backup copies too: Having to close your business because the main computer room got a water leak isn't a fun prospect.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback. I will try to convince management to invest in more storage :-)